# How to improve the performance of indexed search in typo3?

Tags: search, typo3, indexed

I have used typo3 indexed search. I have many pages around 50000. Indexed search become too slow.

When i search for the word, it takes more time. How to improve the performance of front end search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use e.g. the [solr Extension](http://www.typo3-solr.com)

Comment: it's due to the architecture of indexed_search that it's slow for big sites

Comment: To whom it may concern: the "solr" extension is more complex to configure. It requires on the server: a Java development Kit (JDK), a Tomcat server, and solr itself. Quite a task to setup and configure for the non-java programmer/admin, and not for the uninitiated. - Moreover there are elaborate dependencies with other typo3 extensions (check the "version matrix) on their website.